# How to pass vue js data to php variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, vue.js

```
                            <section class="scans">
                                  <h3>Scans</h3>

                                  <ul v-if="scans.length === 0">
                                    <li class="empty">No scans yet</li>
                                  </ul>

                                  <transition-group name="scans" tag="ul">

                                            <li v-for="scan in scans" :key="scan.date" :title="scan.content">

                                            {{ scan.content }}

                                            </li>
                                  </transition-group>

                             </section>
```

How can i pass '{{ scan.content }}' to a html element (textbox) or php ($scanned) variable?

Comment: Are you asking how to display `scan.content` in a textbox?  Or do you want to know how to POST your client-side data to the server so PHP can have access to it?

Comment: I want to know how to post that client-side data to my server side so i can access it via php

Comment: I suggest you look into an AJAX POST of some type (example: [vue-resource](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource) or [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you want your data to be sent either make a form with hidden elements (usually if the user should initiate the post request) or make an AJAX POST directly in Javascript. (if it should be 'seamless'/in the background)

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, i'll give it a try and keep you posted

Answer (score -1):

Figure out how to make Vue send AJAX, maybe following a recent tutorial, like: https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/08/28/vue-js-ajax-recipes/
since apparently simply giving an id to the transition-group and using innerHTML and document.getElementById to fetch the data is for some reason bad form and should be avoided, for some reason...

Comment: Since the data is already in his Vue data, there's no need to use `innerHTML` and DOM lookups to find it.  Vue makes a clear separation between data and presentation which removes the needs to DOM manipulation/querting.

Comment: Patric, I edited the answer, thanks for your suggestion, may I know how exactly does one send data to Vue? I'm a Vue newbie myself!